# Transferring Data between old and new phone

Tags: samsung-smart-switch

TL;DR: Switching from A70 to Fairphone 4. What is the best way to transfer data/settings?

More context: I need to transfer data between two phones: An Samsung Galaxy A70 (2019) and a Fairphone 4. Both will be running stock and Android 11.

What is the best way to basically mirror or copy my old A70 to the new Fairphone 4?

I used Smartswitch when previously switching but I don't know if on can switch from a Galaxy phone to a NON-Galaxy phone using Smart switch.

Samsung's Websites more or less aggressively markets Smart Switch to be the way to switch to a Galaxy phone from your old potentially NON-Galaxy phone. Of course there is some marketing talk involved in there trying to promote Galaxy Phones.

In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kB3r9O2BACw) another way is showcased but I didn't see this way when switching to and from an Android phone prior.

I am afraid the A70 is going to die soon and I am unsure if my Smart Switch backup on my PC will be sufficient so I am asking this question before the Fairphone 4 even arrived.

Thank you for your help in advance! (and sorry if my English isn't perfect)

Comment: I don't know if Smartswitch will work, but in my opinion the best way for migrating data is directly between two phones (direct USB connection).

Comment: yeah yeah, but "how". Its not just gonna magically transfer the data yk. And I'd like to keep apps and setting data and such just all in one

Comment: The new phone starts with the set-up wizard which includes as data migration tool that can make use of a direct USB connection. At least that is the way it had worked with my Pixel 4a. I would suggest to got to a Fairphone related forum and ask there if such an USB direct transfer is possible with Fairphone 4. Note that a lot of apps can (especially banking/financial related) as they use AndroidKeyStore which contains entries that are by definition bound to the device and thus can not be exported or migrated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I did not know that but I do remember getting Logged out of such apps. I will see if the data migration tool is a thing on the fairphone. Maybe it wasn't a thing on my prior Galaxy's because, well Smart Switch. If it isn't, well thats an inconvenience but not the worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just received my FP 4 (and my A70 is still alive!) and it does indeed have the data migrating feature. Not the one with the USB-C cable but a wireless version through Google Cloud. I guess that works too just waiting for it to download now!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure either if you can transfer to a non-Samsung Device.  But the process is as follows

**On Old Phone**

1. Log on to the Google Account you want to use.
2. Go to Settings
3. Select Accounts (or Account and Backup)
4. Select Backup (it could be a toggle)
5. On some phones you will have a selection list, select all
6. Proceed to Backup

**On New Phone**

1. Activate (log into) your Google account with teh backup
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to System
4. Go to Backup
5. Toggle **Backup to Google Drive**
6. Proceed

I have listed one option, there are others there.

[From support.fairphone](https://support.fairphone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047671191-FP3-Transfer-your-data-to-your-new-Fairphone)

Comment: Also thank you! I will look into this incase the data migration doesn't pop up from itself